# cordova iosrtc app crash on iphone device - 'NSInternalInconsistencyException

Tags: swift, objective-c, cordova-plugins, cordova-ios

**i have an app crash issue on ios real device**

> ```
> libc++abi: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
> dyld4 config: DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/system/introspection DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES=/Developer/usr/lib/libBacktraceRecording.dylib:/Developer/usr/lib/libMainThreadChecker.dylib:/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GPUTools.framework/libglInterpose.dylib:/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DTDDISupport.framework/libViewDebuggerSupport.dylib
> ```

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Call must be made on main thread'
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

> Apple macOS: 11.6.6 Big Sur Xcode: 13.2.1 ios-deploy: 1.11.4
> CocoaPods: 1.11.3 cordova : 11.0.0 cordova-platform-ios : 6.2.0
> webrtc-adapter-version : 8.1.1

Comment: There is no stacktrace? But from the error, you need to do a call in mainthread while you did it in a background thread. UI updates needs to be done in main thread.

Comment: @Larme plesase give detailed idea's , i use the code bellow                                                                         // Obj-C
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
}

// Swift
DispatchQueue.main.async {
} isthat correct soution for mainthread issue

Comment: Without the call stacktrace, message before/after *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', it's hard to tell...

Comment: @larme i found the solution. the problem is remote-injection-plugin, so i customize the the ios platform thank You!

Answer (score 1):

This issue was created by using some deprecated plugins, so remove the deprecated plugin and find alternative sources.